# Possible to match multiple conditions in one case statement and pass them as variables?

Tags: bash, case

I have a bash script where I want to set a case variable. For file1 there are two different NUMBER variables that I then I want to pass to a text file.

I have tried the following:

```
case $FILE in
   "file1")
    NUMBER="12";;&
    NUMBER="34";;&
   "file2")
    NUMBER="56";;
esac

mv textfile.txt $NUMBER.txt
```

where I want the output for file1 to be the following:

```
12.txt
24.txt
```

I am getting the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `;;&'
```

Do you have any suggestions? thanks so much.

Comment: It isn't even an issue of the case statement. You are giving one value to a variable and then overwriting it. What do you actually want to do here? Do you want to make two copies of the original `textfile.txt`, one named `12.txt` and another named `24.txt`?

Comment: yes! is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the logic of what you are trying to do won't work. You cannot assign two values to a variable, when you assign the second, the first is lost. This means that this would never do what you want:

```
number=1 ## $number is now 1
number=2 ## $number is now 2, and the original value 1 has been replaced.
```

So, in order to make two copies of a file, you need to use a different approach.

Here are some ideas (note that I put your variable names in lower case: it's bad practice to use CAPS for shell script variable names since by convention, the global environment variables are capitalized, so this can lead to naming collisions and hard to debug issues):

- Make one copy inside the `case` statement, the other afterwards:

  ```bash
  case $file in
    "file1")
      cp textfile.txt 23.txt
      number="34";;
     "file2")
      number="56";;
  esac

  mv textfile.txt $number.txt
  ```
- use an array instead

  ```bash
  case $file in
    "file1")
      numbers+=(23 34);;
     "file2")
      numbers+=(56);;
  esac

  for number in "${numbers[@]}"; do
    cp textfile.txt "$number".txt
  done
  rm textfile.txt
  ```

  One drawback with this approach is that it does everything by copying instead of moving so it will be slightly slower since the first approach has at least one `mv` operation. You can't have more than one `mv`, but at least you can modify this so it makes one `mv` and so is as fast as the first approach:

  ```bash
  case $file in
    "file1")
      numbers+=(23 34);;
     "file2")
      numbers+=(56);;
  esac

  ## Iterate over all except the first element of the array
  for number in "${numbers[@]:1}"; do
    cp textfile.txt "$number".txt
  done
  ## move the file using the first number in the array
  mv textfile.txt "${numbers[0]}".txt
  ```

Comment: thanks so much this works perfectly!